# How to join Consecutive Date Ranges in linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

so i have these data example

```
projects   startdate    enddate
prj A      01 Jan 2019  10 Feb 2019
prj B      29 Jan 2019  15 Mar 2019
prj C      21 Mar 2019  02 May 2019
prj D      07 May 2019  10 Jun 2019
prj E      11 Jun 2019  30 Jul 2019
```

and i want to make list object that each item contains consecutive project list using linq lambda
the grouping result is roughly like this

```
[
   [prj A, prj B],
   [prj C],
   [prj D, prj E]
]
```

- prj A and B is grouped because daterange prj A is overlapped with prj
  B
- since there is space between enddate prj B and startdate prj C, so
  prj C is in different group
- prj D and E is grouped because startdate
  prj E is the nextday from enddate prj D

so how to create grouping like that using linq lambda?
thanks

Comment: What if A overlaps B and B overlaps C?

Comment: then A, B & C is joined to 1 group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `GroupBy` them via Linq, because each item in group may not have common grouping key among other ones or it can't be found, instead only one common key exists between two neighborhoods. [Try another approach:](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T1RDrb)

```
var result = new List<List<string>>();
var projects = new List<Project>
{
    new Project{ Name = "prj A",
        startdate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), enddate = new DateTime(2019, 2, 10) },
    new Project{ Name = "prj B",
        startdate = new DateTime(2019, 1, 29), enddate = new DateTime(2019, 3, 15) },
    new Project{ Name = "prj C",
        startdate = new DateTime(2019, 3, 21), enddate = new DateTime(2019, 5, 2) },
    new Project{ Name = "prj D",
        startdate = new DateTime(2019, 5, 7), enddate = new DateTime(2019, 6, 10) },
    new Project{ Name = "prj E",
        startdate = new DateTime(2019, 6, 11), enddate = new DateTime(2019, 7, 30) }
};
projects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.startdate).ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < projects.Count; i++)
{
    var project = projects[i];
    if (projects[0] != project 
        && 
        (project.startdate - projects[i - 1].enddate).TotalDays < 2)
        result.Last().Add(project.Name);
    else
        result.Add(new List<string> { project.Name });                                    
}

foreach(var gr in result)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", gr));
//prj A, prj B
//prj C
//prj D, prj E
```

Comment: You can use Linq to group them. You just need to make a custom extension method that groups adjacent rows as long there is overlap.

Comment: @dfhwze, please, show me where you used `GroupBy` at your answer?

Comment: I don't use _GroupBy_ since I am grouping based on a _function_, not a _key_. Your statement that we can't group using LINQ is correct in the sense that _GroupBy_ can't be used, but incorrect in a broader sense of what _grouping_ is. Is a key required to be called a group?

Comment: @dfhwze, it is comment, which I wanted to hear from you.

Comment: Since you have now updated your answer to include _GroupBy_ our comments are mute. We can both agree that _GroupBy_ cannot be used.

Comment: so i ended up using loop instead
using linq require more workaround

Answer (score 2):

You can write an extension method adhering to LINQ style. `JoinBy` acts as an analytical *lag* function. It requires an `orderBy` and `keySelector` to determine adjacent values to evaluate. The `join` is used to decide when adjacent values can be joined.

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> JoinBy<TSource, TOrderKey, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TOrderKey> orderBy,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        Func<TKey, TKey, bool> join)
    {
        var results = new List<List<TSource>>();
        var orderedSource = new List<TSource>(source).OrderBy(orderBy).ToArray();

        if (orderedSource.Length > 0)
        {
            var group = new List<TSource> { orderedSource[0] };
            results.Add(group);
            if (orderedSource.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < orderedSource.Length; i++)
                {
                    var lag = orderedSource[i - 1];
                    var current = orderedSource[i];
                    if (join(keySelector(lag), keySelector(current)))
                    {
                        group.Add(current);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        group = new List<TSource> { current };
                        results.Add(group);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

..and use it to group adjacent projects together..

```
public class Project
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Begin { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestCase1()
{
    var projects = new List<Project>() {
          new Project { Name = "A", Begin = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), End = new DateTime(2000, 12, 31) }
        , new Project { Name = "B", Begin = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), End = new DateTime(2001, 12, 31) }
        , new Project { Name = "C", Begin = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1), End = new DateTime(2010, 12, 31) }
        , new Project { Name = "D", Begin = new DateTime(2010, 6, 1), End = new DateTime(2010, 7, 1) }
     };

    var grouped = projects.JoinBy(
        x => x.Begin,
        x => (begin: x.Begin, end: x.End),
        (x1, x2) => x2.begin <= x1.end.AddDays(1) && x1.begin <= x2.end.AddDays(1));

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var grp in grouped)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Join(", ", grp.Select(x => x.Name)));
    }

    var rendered = builder.ToString();

    // rendered =>
    // A, B
    // C, D
}
```

EDIT: another test case from comments

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCase2_FromComments()
{
    var projects = new List<Project>() {
          new Project { Name = "A", Begin = new DateTime(2019, 4, 2), End = new DateTime(2019, 8, 17) }
        , new Project { Name = "B", Begin = new DateTime(2019, 6, 1), End = new DateTime(2019, 7, 1) }
     };

    var grouped = projects.JoinBy(
        x => x.Begin,
        x => (begin: x.Begin, end: x.End),
        (x1, x2) => x2.begin <= x1.end.AddDays(1) && x1.begin <= x2.end.AddDays(1));

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var grp in grouped)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Join(", ", grp.Select(x => x.Name)));
    }

    var rendered = builder.ToString();

    // rendered =>
    // A, B
}
```

Comment: thanks, most elegant solutions so far...
i'll try to integrate this to my code (the actual code has complex objects & complex linq)

Comment: this work on most cases, but if there project that fully overlap another project like
prj A - 02 Apr 2019 - 17 Aug 2019
prj B - 01 Jun 2019 - 01 Jul 2019
prj B would create another group insted joining with prj A in 1 group

Comment: @TanggonJodiIsmana I just tested, and it still groups ok (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

Using a variation of the APL Scan operator (like `Aggregate`, only returns the intermediate results) that works with pairs of items, you can create a `GroupBy` that takes a predicate lambda over pairs and creates groups as long as its value is true:

```
public static class IenumerableExt {
    // TKey combineFn((TKey Key, T Value) prevKeyItem, T curItem)
    //      prevKeyItem.Key = Previous Key (initially, seedKey)
    //      prevKeyItem.Value = Previous Item
    //      curItem = Current Item
    //      returns TKey for Current Item
    public static IEnumerable<(TKey Key, T Value)> ScanToPairs<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> src, TKey seedKey, Func<(TKey Key, T Value), T, TKey> combineFn) {
        using (var srce = src.GetEnumerator())
            if (srce.MoveNext()) {
                var prevkv = (seedKey, srce.Current);

                while (srce.MoveNext()) {
                    yield return prevkv;
                    prevkv = (combineFn(prevkv, srce.Current), srce.Current);
                }
                yield return prevkv;
            }
    }

    // bool testFn(T prevVal, T curVal)
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, T>> GroupPairsByWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, bool> testFn) =>
        src.ScanToPairs(1, (kvp, cur) => testFn(kvp.Value, cur) ? kvp.Key : kvp.Key + 1)
           .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```

With this extension, you can easily group the projects:

```
var ans = projects.GroupPairsByWhile((prev,cur) => cur.startdate <= prev.enddate.AddDays(1));
```